# Tracing coordinate of clicked Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3

Lets say I want a mouse click event listener to trace (console print) the x coordinate of a sprite clicked. this is what Ive got, which is wrong.

```
    public function field()
    {
        ....
        //nodes is an array containing node sprite objects
        for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){  
            var single_node:Node;
            single_node = nodes[i];             
            single_node.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNodeClick)
        }
        ... 

    }

private function onNodeClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(this.x); // should output single_node object x coordinate 
}
```

I believe this.x is referring to the classes property x, however i would like to refer to the single_node object. 
currently console is outputting 0, regardless of what sprite i click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.target.x`

`Event` has a [`target`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#target) property which represents the object you've added an event listener to.

A side note though, I'd be more inclined to have the listeners set up in your own Node class and trace the `x` property from there.